# Content editable DIV with BREAK's or just DIV's

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that is content editable and I use this div as an Input for my code. The problem is the user input. If a user writes something in the div, it's just a normal text, but if he makes a new line there is in a div. Can I somehow make it that the first line is also in a div? Or is it possible to just make break elements if there is a new line?

By the way, I want to use a content editable div, because I want to color some parts of the text different that others, why I can't use a text area.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
"1"
<div>2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The behavior seems browser dependent.  Yet, adding display: inline-block appears to automatic div insertion.

Comment: THis might be an XY problem. What's wrong with the fact that a div is inserted? For example, if your goal was to get the text of the contenteditable div, you could try using its `textContent` property.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the code below if you set the first child element tag as a `div`, each added child will be a `div` as well.

```js
var div  = document.querySelector("div[contenteditable=true]");
div.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.children)
});
console.log(div);
```

```html
<div contenteditable=true>
  <div>‎</div>
<div>
```

**Edit:** *To have any character at the beginning and be able to click it, copy the invisible character in the first child div.*

or copy it here: `‎`

Comment: In your Demo it seems to work, but for me if I do this:
´´´
<div contenteditable=true>
  <div>‎</div>
<div>
´´´

I get :
´´´
"2"
<br>
"3"
<div></div>
´´´

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Using backspace removes the child div

Comment: Thank you, I just check every keydown if it is clear and if its true, I set the innerHTML = "<div><br></div>" 
this seems to work for me, even if it is not as good as I thought it could be.

Comment: you can fix it with `event.prevent()`, if there is only one div without content in the input event listener

Comment: I found a very simple solution. I just use innerText instead of innerHTML. Now I have to rewrite some parts but the code should be much simpler that earlier. Thank you :)